# how to get the number of times user has given inputs in c#

Tags: c#

hey I am creating a guessing game here it the code ,

```
        Random random = new Random();
        int x =  random.Next(0, 11);
        Console.WriteLine("Guess a number betweeen 1 and 10");

        while (true)
        {
            int y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (y > x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You guessed high !");
            }

            if (y < x)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("You guessed low !");
            }

            if (y == x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You guessed right !");
                Console.ReadLine();
                break;


            }


        }
```

now what I want to do is that know the number of times the user has guessed and store it in a variable , so how can this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a counter and every loop increase the counter by one.

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int x = random.Next(0, 11);
        Console.WriteLine("Guess a number betweeen 1 and 10");

        // create a counter for the total total guessed answers.
        int totalQuessed = 0;
        bool gameOver = false;
        while (!gameOver)
        {
            int y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (y > x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"You guessed high !");
            }

            if (y < x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You guessed low !");
            }

            if (y == x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You guessed right !");
                gameOver = true;
            }
            // increase by one
            totalQuessed++;
            Console.WriteLine("You've guessed: {0} times", totalQuessed);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: In case the player will guess the correct number, `totalGuessed` counter will not increase (because of `break`) and it should in all cases

Comment: I makes more sense to initial `gameOver=false` `while(!gameOver)`